# Why does calling the InternetReadFileEx function with IRF_NO_WAIT flag still wait?

Tags: winapi, wininet

I'm using a synchronous wininet request and calling [`InternetReadFileEx()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa385105.aspx) with the `IRF_NO_WAIT` flag, but the function still blocks waiting for data. Why is that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the [MSDN docs](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa385105(VS.85).aspx), the meaning of `IRF_NO_WAIT` is described as:

> Do not wait for data. If there is data available, the function returns either the amount of data requested or the amount of data available (whichever is smaller).

Mysteriously, it leaves the case where there is *not* data available undefined.  Apparently, if there is *no* data, it blocks until there is some.

Comment: Oddly, IRF_NO_WAIT and IRF_USE_CONTEXT have the same value if you look at wininet.h.  They are both defined to 0x00000008.  IRF_ASYNC is 0x00000001 and IRF_SYNC is 0x00000004.  If this flag is used as a bitmask, then IRF_NO_WAIT specifies neither IRF_ASYNC nor IRF_SYNC.  I guess that means it doesn't force sync operations and it doesn't force async operations, but it could use either?  Really, the documentation just leaves us clueless on how this actually works.

Answer (score 1):

A possible workaround is to use InternetQueryOption() to get an INTERNET_DIAGNOSTIC_SOCKET_INFO structure, and then pass the SOCKET handle to ::select() with a timeout of {0, 0} to determine if data is available without blocking.

Answer (score 0):

What IRF_NO_WAIT means is to not wait for *all* of the requested data buffer to be filled. However, it will still wait for *some* data to arrive. If no data is arriving, it blocks.